# <asp:loginview> gives me 401 UNAUTHORIZED error when I try and authenticate

Tags: 401

I'm working my way through Randy Drisgills book 'Professional SharePointBranding and User Interface Design' In Ch8 p232 Step5 he explains how to use the  funtion to hide the Ribbon from Anonymous access users.

Step 5.
This process begins with the User Login button; it is one of the more complex steps
because you will be adding an `<asp:LoginView>`, as described previously in the “Handling
the Ribbon for Anonymous Users” section. Replace the simple HTML link with the
`<asp:LoginView>`, as follows:

```
<div class=”customTop customPagePadding”>
  <asp:LoginView id=”LoginView” runat=”server”>
    <AnonymousTemplate>
      <a href=”/_layouts/authenticate.aspx” class=”customLogin”
         title=”User Login”>User Login</a>
      <style type=”text/css”>
        body #s4-ribbonrow {
          display: none;
        }
      </style>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
  </asp:LoginView>
</div>
```

I have set this up (as per step 5) with Anonymous Access and it seems to work ok however when I click on 'User Login' to authenticate with my 'admin' account it doesn't seem to recognise it, prompts me 3 times then gives me a '401 Unauthorized' error.
Strange thing is, when I reopen the site homepage it opens in edit mode.

My admin a/c is in the Site Owners Group and has full control. I've tried setting up dummy a/c accounts and adding them to the group with the same result.

I have also tried applied the kb article on this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 but with no joy.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this or how I can find out what's causing it? specific log files etc..?

Thanks,

Steve